# Data is not getting added into my database on php my admin

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin, localhost, wampserver

I am using wamp server.I am trying to store the data which user fill in my form.But i don't know why its not getting added.
These are my **php files**:(all files wrote in notepad++)

**init.php:**

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$db_user = "harsh";
$db_password = "password";
$db_name = "user_db";

 $con = mysqli_connect($host,$db_user,$db_password,$db_name);

?>
```

**register1.php:**

```
<?php
require "init.php";

$name = $_POST["name"];
$adharnumber = $_POST["adharnumber"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$contact = $_POST["contact"];

$sql="select * from individualuser_info where email like '".$email."';";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$response = array();

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    $code = "reg_failed";
    $message = "User already exist....";
    array_push($response,array("code"=>$code,"message"=>$message));
    echo json_encode($response);
}
 else
{


    $sql = "insert into individualuser_info (`".$name."','".$adharnumber."','".$email."','".$password."','".$contact."');";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $code = "reg_success";
    $message = "thank you .now you can login....";
    array_push($response,array("code"=>$code,"message"=>$message));
    echo json_encode($response);
}
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

My form **register_test.html:**

```
<html>

<body>
<form action ="register1.php", method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Name : </td><td><input type="text" name="name"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Adhar number : </td><td><input type="text" name="adharnumber"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Email:</td><td><input type="text" name="email"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="password"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Contact:</td><td><input type="text" name="contact"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type = "submit" value="Register"/></td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

After making this files after starting wampserver 
when  i am typing **localhost/register_test.html** in chrome url.
It displays the form but unexpectedly in the email field it shows **loacalhost** automatically and in  password field displays some password.
And after filling the details when i click on register it shows message
**[{"code":"reg_success","message":"thank you .now you can login...."}]**.
But in database **user_db** in my **individiualuser_info** table no records gets added.
**Please help me to solve this.**

Comment: You display a success message but never actually check if the operation was successful.  Take a look at `mysqli_error`.  Your code is wide open to SQL injection, there's a good chance you have a syntax error.

Comment: Your problem is likely the extra ` character after the ( in your insert.  But as David said please protect yourself from sql injection!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says [your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe. Also, if you view error-logs, they should have caught this - developing without errors set to show all is not smart.